# BigCommerce Uploading a blueprint theme

Tags: themes, bigcommerce

I have exported an old Blueprint theme and I would like to import it into a new trial store I have created. The first thing I did was import the blueprint theme directly to the BigCommerce platform but I get the following error:

> TR-600 The .zip file is missing a required file
> (/templates/pages/home.html).

Now, this is expected since the Blueprint theme does not contain that file. Afterward, I saw this tutorial on how you can change your platform to support the Blueprint theme:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/themes/blueprint/#a-foundation-for-creating-themes

I have added the URL snippet provided to my store url:

```
/index.php?ToDo=viewTemplates&dev=enable
```

My active theme is a Stencil theme, as this is the default theme it comes with, and there is no other way to upload a Blueprint theme as of now. I have connected to my BigCommerce platform via
**WebDav** but I cannot seem to find the **Templates** directory as mention on this tutorial

https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Transferring-a-Custom-Theme-from-One-Bigcommerce-Store-to-Another

How I can upload a Blueprint theme to my BigCommerce platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blueprint is a deprecated theme framework that can't be enabled on new stores. Stores that enabled a Blueprint theme prior to 2015 can continue to use it, but any new stores are provisioned only with Stencil.

The documentation you linked on enabling Blueprint developer mode was actually the old process that theme partners used to use to make updates to Blueprint themes that were sold in the BigCommerce theme marketplace--it won't switch a Stencil store over to the legacy framework.

Although it isn't possible to upload your Blueprint theme to your trial store, I'd recommend taking a look at Stencil. It's built on a modern JS framework and incorporates a lot of features that Blueprint did not:

https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/stencil-technology-base

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I also did talk to tech support about this, as you mention, unless you have a Blueprint theme already installed on your platform you cannot import the theme. Thanks for your help.